# Sum Array values of a Firestore field

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to get around to sum values of an `array` from a Firestore document field.

Irrespective of what I do, I continue to get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

My requirement is as follows:

I have a db Collection -> "ALLUSERS" and the each document id is the phone number of the user.

Under this document, I have Collections "CHEMISTRY" and a document "Summary". In this, I have a number array of Chapters with points.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFiri.png)

I am able to get this detail with DocuementSnapshot.get(...the chapter...). However, once I try to sum the values inside the array, I get the above error.

Below is the code where I tried to sum the same with stream.

```
                         for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                String phonenumber = document.getString("phonenumb");
                                students.add(phonenumber);
                                chemistry.document(phonenumber)
                                        .get()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData();

                                                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                                                    if (entry.getKey().contains("chemchaps")) {
                                                        List<String> stringList = (List<String>) entry.getValue();
                                                        List<Integer> integerList = stringList.stream()
                                                                .map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
                                                        Integer maxValue = Collections.max(integerList);
                                                        Toast("Max Value " + integerList + " " + maxValue);
                                                        for(int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++){
                                                            String chapterNo = "Chapter"+String.valueOf(maxValue);
                                                            String chapternumb = "chapter"+String.valueOf(maxValue);
                                                            chemistry.document(phonenumber).collection("CHEMISTRY").document("Summary")
                                                                    .get()
                                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                                               if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                                                   DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                                                                                   List<Integer> chaptersum = (List<Integer>) documentSnapshot.get(chapternumb);
                                                                                   long intsum = chaptersum.stream().mapToLong(Integer::longValue).sum();
                                                                                   //chaptersum.stream().reduce(0, (a, b)-> a+b);
                                                                                   //chaptersum.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                                                                                   Toast("Chapter Nos "+chapterNo + " "+ chaptersum+ " "+ intsum);
                                                                               }
                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                Toast("Map data " + map);
                                            }
                                        });
```

I get the error at this line:

```
long intsum = chaptersum.stream().mapToLong(Integer::longValue).sum();
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following line of error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Because you are added to `chapter1` array numbers, which are basically stored as long values and **not** as integers. So to solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
List<Integer> chaptersum = (List<Integer>) documentSnapshot.get(chapternumb);                                                                            
long intsum = chaptersum.stream().mapToLong(Integer::longValue).sum();
```

to

```
List<Long> chaptersum = (List<Long>) documentSnapshot.get(chapternumb);                                                                            
long intsum = chaptersum.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
```

See, the list now is of type `Long` and we create the sum using Long values.